ionic angular 8 get component instance
I've tried different ways to get the component instance after creating a modal using ionic and angular, however nothing worked for me. Could you please help me to understand, how can I get a component instance reference after creting a modal? The sample code is listed below:
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: MyCustomComponent,
  cssClass: "some-css-class",
  componentProps:
  {
    item: item
  },
  backdropDismiss: false
});

modal.canDismiss = async (data?: any, roleDismiss?: string) => {
  let can = false;
  return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => resolve(can));
}

for example, in the canDismiss handler I'd like to verify some actual component instance properties, however I can't seem to find a proper way of doing this. How can I access the MyCustomCompnent instance after creating the modal?
I'm using ionic angular 8, angular 18.1.3

create service that used for communicate between modal and parent component
export class ModalService {
  private modalInstanceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  modalInstance$ = this.modalInstanceSubject.asObservable();

  setModalInstance(instance: any) {
    this.modalInstanceSubject.next(instance);
  }
}

In MyCustomComponent, inject ModalService and set instance of the component
export class MyCustomComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.modalService.setModalInstance(this);
  }

  // Example property you want to access
  someProperty: boolean = false;
}

In parent component where you create modal, inject ModalService and subscribe to modalInstance$ to get instance of the modal
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private modalController: ModalController, private modalService: ModalService) {}

  async openModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: MyCustomComponent,
      cssClass: 'some-css-class',
      componentProps: {
        item: 'some item'
      },
      backdropDismiss: false
    });

    modal.present();

    this.modalService.modalInstance$.subscribe(instance => {
      if (instance) {
        // Now you can access the instance of MyCustomComponent
        console.log(instance.someProperty);

        modal.canDismiss = async (data?: any, roleDismiss?: string) => {
          // Access the component instance properties here
          return instance.someProperty;
        };
      }
    });
  }
}

